# Lost my rotary selector (Tab Key Pie Menus)

Tags: interface, add-on

I just updated to v2.79 and found that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key mode selector is gone. When the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed, a rotary selector appears that allows selection of any of the available modes. I had added it under v2.78c to make it easy to select different modes. I can't remember where I got it. I remember finding it in a video tutorial, but which one (I've favorite-ed about 200 so far).

Answer (score 3):

The [**Pie Menu**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html?highlight=pie%20menu#add-on-preferences) is an addon

You can enable/disable it on the User Preferences Add-On section (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

[image]

Note that one can customize which Blender menus are displayed as pie menus using *Preferences* settings group in the User Preferences > Pie menu rollout (settings are available only after the addon is enabled):

[image]

Comment: Is "Comments" the correct way to thank those who have responded to my question? Thanks for the quick response. It is amazing how thoroughly one comes to depend on things.

Comment: No need to post thanks, you can vote for answers that are helpful and also mark them as accepted. Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).Also, take the [tour] to understand how this site works.